# How do i select a random row in admin.view localhost sqlalchemy?

Tags: sql, database, random, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Hi im having hard thinking of how to select a random row from sqlalchemy in a localhost admin database view. I want it to select a random list but the ones with user assigned so it selects a random raffle like `Colour:Ruby up1:dgg2 up2:fh73.below is where the code for the local host database session & view of the database in modelview localhost.

```
admin = Admin(app, name='raffles', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Raffle, db.session))
```

i need help adding code to select a raffle from there

heres the app.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView


from forms import RaffleForm
from models import db, get_db_uri, User, Raffle
from utils import assign_raffles_to_user, seed_raffles_into_db

from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail
from mail import mail
from flask_mail import Message

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'osman33454@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'Password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True






app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = get_db_uri()
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some-random-secret-key'
mail.init_app(app)

db.app = app
db.init_app(app)
db.create_all()
seed_raffles_into_db()


admin = Admin(app, name='raffles', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Raffle, db.session))


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = RaffleForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        email = form.email.data
        # check if user exists
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).all()
        if not user:
            user = User(email=email)
            db.session.add(user)
        else:
            user = user[0]
        # assign required raffles to user
        assign_raffles_to_user(form.raffle_count.data, user)
        return redirect(url_for('success'))

    return render_template('home.html', form=form)


@app.route('/success', methods=['GET'])
def success():
    return render_template('success.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

and heres the utils.py

```
# utility functions go here
import random
import os
from uuid import uuid4

import constants
from models import Raffle, User
from flask_mail import Message
from flask_mail import Mail
from mail import mail

def generate_raffles(count):
    for i in xrange(count):
        colour = constants.COLORS[i % constants.COLORS_LEN]
        uniq = uuid4().hex
        uniq_p1, uniq_p2 = uniq[:4], uniq[4:8]
        yield (colour, uniq_p1, uniq_p2)


def seed_raffles_into_db(max_raffles=constants.MAX_RAFFLES):
    if is_inited():
        print 'Raffles have already been seeded...'
        return False
    from app import db
    print 'Seeding raffles...'
    for raffle_colour, raffle_up1, raffle_up2 in generate_raffles(max_raffles):
        raffle = Raffle(
            colour=raffle_colour,
            up1=raffle_up1,
            up2=raffle_up2,
        )
        print "Adding", raffle
        db.session.add(raffle)

    db.session.commit()
    mark_as_inited()
    return True


def get_unused_raffles(raffle_count):
    return (
        Raffle.query.filter_by(
            user=None
        ).limit(
            constants.RAFFLE_PADDING + raffle_count
        )
    ).all()


def mark_as_inited():
    open(constants.INIT_FILE_PATH, 'w').close()


def is_inited():
    return os.path.exists(constants.INIT_FILE_PATH)


def assign_raffles_to_user(raffle_count, user):
    from app import db
    raffles = get_unused_raffles(raffle_count)

    for raffle in random.sample(raffles, raffle_count):
      print "Assigning {0} to {1}".format(raffle, user)
      msg = Message('Raffle assigned', sender = 'osman.soloking009@outlook.com', recipients = [user.email]) 
      msg.body = myRaffle = "Assigning {0} to {1}".format(raffle, user)
      mail.send(msg)
      raffle.user = user





    db.session.commit()
    return True
```

[link to see image of my admin view localhost defined tables -where I want the selection to take place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETKhz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

**Select a random row with MySQL:**

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

**Select a random row with IBM DB2**

```
SELECT column, RAND() as IDX 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

**Select a random row with Microsoft SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 5 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**Select a random record with Oracle:**

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 5
```

**Select a random row with PostgreSQL:**

```
SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 5
```

**Select a random row with SQLite:**

```
SELECT column  FROM table 
ORDER BY 
RANDOM() LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: for sql & where does that go into

Comment: @KimFake Which database you are using?

Comment: Im using sqlite

Comment: @KimFake See edited code for sqlite & you have to check your code where is select statement and modify that

Comment: syntax error SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1

Comment: how do I modify it to my requiremnts

Comment: @KimFake what is your table name ?

Comment: I have two tables raffle and user

Comment: do I need to import any code like this  from  sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func, select

Comment: @KimFake Open your database first. go there and write sql to run and see five  random row come out, then after you have to check into your code where the select code is written so change it

Comment: oh how can I create cmd version of that it does via a python terminal so I would open it and print 5 different raffles via cmd